# JPQL to get parent based on child condition

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

My problem:

I have two entities: Person and User which extends from person:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Person {
 .....
}

@Entity
public class User extends Person{
 private string alias;
 ......
}
```

I need to get back all Person which are not User and all User based on a condition on User attributes.

I tried to used type and treat in a JPQL Query

```
@Query("SELECT p from Person p where type(p) = Person OR (type(p) = User and treat(p as User).alias = 'toto'")
```

but when test this query, I only get User which alias is 'toto', the query does not bring back all the other Person...

Can someone help me?

Comment: According to the query requirements, this must be achieved on two queries: one query would return all `people` that aren't `users`, and the other query would return all `users` that match the conditions. If you want to store both queries's results in a single result set, I recommend use `union` operator, so you'll union your queries by using it. For example:

`select *
from Person
...
union
select *
from User
where ...`

For see a detailed explanation of  `union` operator, check here: [SQL Union](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp)

Comment: I wish I could have avoid 2 requests, but this solution is the simpliest